# How to retrieve an index within a lambda for a concatenated range?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

I have the following code:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace ranges;
    namespace views = ranges::views;

    auto v1 = std::deque<double>({ 123.080, 123.110, 123.105, 123.090, 123.095 });
    auto v2 = std::deque<double>({ 123.100, 123.120, 123.115, 123.070, 123.105 });

    auto vc = ranges::views::concat(v1, v2); 
    
    auto lambda = [&](auto& elem){
        const auto index = &elem - &vc[0];
        if (index == 0 || index + 1 > vc.size()) return false;
        if ((vc[index - 1] > vc[index] && vc[index] < vc[index + 1])
            || (vc[index - 1] < vc[index] && vc[index] > vc[index + 1]))      
            return true;
    };

    //auto pv = vc | views::transform(lambda);
    auto pv = vc | views::filter(lambda);

    for(auto p : pv)
    {
        std::cout << p << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But the `const auto index = &elem - &vc[0];` statement is causing a problem as the concat isn't a contiguous area of memory. It gives the following results:

```
123.11, 123.09,
```

When it should give:

```
123.110, 123.090, 123.120, 123.070,
```

These are filtered values that form the peaks (`vc[index-1] < vc[index] && vc[index] > vc[index+1]`) and troughs (`vc[index-1] > vc[index] && vc[index] < vc[index+1]`) of the concatentated view of the two vectors resulting  in a seperate view (`pv`) from the original `vc`.

How can I create an index within the lambda expression which is compatible with the `ranges::concat` view, please? Alternatively, is there a better way to do this with `ranges`?

A live play area is provided: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vE7e53EP5)

Comment: `ranges::view::enumerate`?

Comment: @jarod42 I'm not aware of this method, how does it work exactly please?

Comment: @Andrew, can you please explain (in the question) what you are trying to do? I looks like the second `if` in your lambda is kind of returning `true`/`false` depending on the "curvature" of 3 adjacent points.... but I don't really understand.

Comment: Isn't `const auto index = &elem - &vc[0]` assuming all the memory is contiguous when you are using [deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)'s which do not use contiguous memory? From your lambda, I think you want to take `vc` then have a 3-element element window, create a 3-element tuple then make one step in the `vc` sequence and repeat until you cannot create a 3-element tuple.

Comment: @DanielDearlove I'm unaware of how else to create an index. This is a method I found on the web somewhere. Can you suggest alternative methods?

Comment: is `views::filter` guaranteed to traverse the range in order? I assume so. If that's the case you can just track the index yourself by incrementing an integer every time the lambda is called.

Comment: @kevin, that's a good idea, I was looking for something more complex! Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/hE9sesT58

Comment: @Andrew, my ranges knowledge is only what I can look up in the [documentation](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/). I often use RxMarbles to think about this sort of problem and I think you are after something a [buffer](https://rxmarbles.com/#buffer) or a [bufferCount](https://rxmarbles.com/#bufferCount) operation. Run over `vc` 3 times, once skipping zero items, once skipping one item then once skipping two items. Concatenate the sequences together and use your lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global index seems the wrong way.

I would do something like:

```
auto is_extrema = [](auto r3){
    return r3[0] < r3[1] && r3[1] > r3[2]
        || r3[0] > r3[1] && r3[1] < r3[2];
};
auto pv = vc | views::sliding(3) | views::filter(is_extrema);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4z41hPe4v)